# How do I reverse the order of two words in a string?

Tags: perl

I have a string like this:

```
$a = "Mike , Tree ";
```

I want to reverse it to `"Tree, Mike"`.

Is there any function to do that?

Comment: i am dont know which one i can accepted answer .. because both answer is good ...

Comment: Is the changed whitespace significant?

Comment: Then both answers are missing a space between the comma and the second word.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`reverse`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html) function:

```
$reversed = join(",", reverse split(",", $string));
```

Comment: hey that's a fancy feature in perl... I like.

Comment: This sample code is not using the reverse function in scalar context.

Comment: Nice..Looks very "functional". :)

Answer (score 10):

Split the string into two strings, flip them, and rejoin them.

Or, use a regex:

```
$a =~ s/(.+),(.+)/\2,\1/g;
```

Comment: Better than Roque answer from my point of view as the regex allow you more control on how to deal with extra space. In your case I would exactly do $a =~ s/(\S+)\s*,\s*(\S+)/\2, \1/g;

Comment: \1, etc in the replacement side is long deprecated and will trigger a warning; do this instead: `$a =~ s/(.+),(.+)/$2,$1/g;`

Comment: The `g` modifier seems superfluous here, doesn't it?

Comment: **@radius:** in rogue's answer you could still do a regex to replace the space, though if you're going to regex, you might as just do it all in one step.

Answer (score 1):

If you are guaranteed the your string that you want to be reversed will be separated by commas then I would split the string at the comma and then go through the array it produces from the length of it to 0 and append it to an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Just for your problem.

```
$a =~ s/([A-Za-z]+)([^A-Za-z]+)([A-Za-z]+)/$3$2$1/;

[JJ@JJ trunk]$ perl -E '$a = "Mike , Tree "; $a =~ s/([A-Za-z]+)([^A-Za-z]+)([A-Za-z]+)/$3$2$1/; say $a;'
Tree , Mike
```