# How do I reverse the order of two words in a string of arabic language?

Tags: string, perl, unicode, bidi

I need to reverse the text direction of an arabic string in perl as I have done it in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saurabh_saxena/ArKyx/2/) using CSS. I am a newbie in perl, so I need some guidance to get my expected result.

I am looking for exactly same results as shown in the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saurabh_saxena/ArKyx/2/). I have tried it using an advice in this [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204668/how-do-i-reverse-the-order-of-two-words-in-a-string).

But this code is actually reversing the order of words in the text. If i do the same with arabic text, it will change its meaning.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Hi @Saurabh u like this one http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/ArKyx/5/

Comment: I think OP wants to do this in Perl. The CSS is just an example of what the expected result should be.

Comment: @sachleen, you are right. I need the exact same results in PERL

Comment: I'm not confident that I understand what you're after.  It appears to me you just want to split like this:  `my( $left, $delim, $right ) = split /(:\s)/, $string; print $right, $delim, $left, "\n";`  At least that produces output (for me) identical to what I'm seeing in your Fiddle, except for alignment to the opposite margin.

Comment: ...or more idiomatically, `$string =~ s/^([^:]+)(:\s+)(\X+)$/$3$2$1/; print "$string\n";`

Comment: What do you use to display the output of the perl program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should store text always in writing order. The direction of text is a property of the Unicode characters that you use, and the programs used for reading text (text editors, web browsers, ..) should implement the [Unicode bi-directional text algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-directional_text) to show it correctly. If you are writing a program to *display* text (as opposed to just generating it), you will find the [Text::Bidi CPAN module](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aBidi) helpful.

With certain mixtures of right-to-left and left-to-right languages the bi-di algorithm may get something wrong. In these cases you can add Unicode directionality marks into your output. For example, if a paragraph in Arabic happens to begin with an English product name you can insert an [RTL mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200F/index.htm) in the beginning so that the whole paragraph is properly displayed. In Perl:

```
my $RLM = "\x{200F}"; # Unicode RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK
say "${RLM}Quux ﻢﻧ ﺎﻠﻣﺎﻠﻛ: \"Centre D\'affaires\"";
```

‏

Comment: I want to use Text::Bidi CPAN module, but I can not install it as it is giving me error. Is there any workaround to use this module? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SaurabhSaxena What do you use to display the output of the perl program?

Comment: @@Joni ... I am scrapping this data using a perl script from a web page. And I need to display the exactly same data on an Interface in which is not compatible with CSS. Otherwise this could have been solved easily.

Comment: What is the interface, GUI of some kind? Windows? GTK+? QT? Tk? If you have a manual for it search for "bidi".

Comment: Can't tell you much, it is more an internal tool. I have checked its manual, it has no support for CSS. It is like .... I can just put data into the database, I cannot change the pre-designed UI, I have to work according to the UI.

Comment: Can you talk to the people who made the UI and ask if they implement the Unicode bi-directional text algorithm and how to enable it? CSS has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @@Joni ... can you just tell me how do i use Text:Bidi CPAN module as I am not able to install it Or is there any other workaround/alternative available?